# android - How to invert delete objects in realm?

Tags: android, database, nosql, realm

i'm talking about i have a list from server and wanna to keep what there as its and what not coming from the server to delete them 
like i have a list of objects and wanna to delete the rest not in the list ?

```
 db.executeTransaction(realm -> {
                    for (QualityControlDetailsResponse response : item.getResult()) {
                        QualityControlDetails controlDetails = db.where(QualityControlDetails.class)
                                .equalTo(QualityControlDetails.Fields.ID, response.getId()).findFirst();
                        if (controlDetails == null) {
                            controlDetails = db.createObject(QualityControlDetails.class, response.getId());
                        }
                        response.copyToRealm(controlDetails, db);
                    }

                });
```

so i want to delete the other items not in my result how to do it ?

i know that i can delete all the table and adding to it whole items but i wanna to keep the items there as it is

Comment: It's in the edit on the accepted answer